# How to sum two frequencies dataset with same variables?

Tags: sql, database, sas, dataset, proc

Hi I want to create two data set of frequencies of tennis players who won a certain number of matches.
Both dataset are int the exact same order

What I do to create the datasets :

```
PROC FREQ data=projet.matchs;
    TABLES player1 / out = table1;
run;

player1            Fréquence    Pourcentage Fréquencecumulée    Pourcentagecumulé
Adrian Mannarino    3              1.18        3                      1.18
Agnieszka Radwanska 2               0.79       5                      1.97
Ajla Tomljanovic    1               0.39       6                      2.36
Albert Ramos        1               0.39       7                      2.76
```

seconde data set table2

```
PROC FREQ data=projet.matchs;
    TABLES player2 / out= table2;
run;

player2              Fréquence  Pourcentage Fréquence cumulée   Pourcentage cumulé
Adrian Mannarino       1          0.39              1                 0.39
Alex Bolt              1          0.39              2                 0.79
Alex De Minaur         1          0.39              3                 1.18
Alexander Zverev       3          1.18              6                 2.36
```

What I Want is to create a new dataset with the sum of table1 and table2.
My dataset are way bigger I have just put the 4th first observations.

Any help would be really appreciate! Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly: a player can be player 1 or player 2 in a match, and you want to get statistics across all their appearances regardless of whether they were player 1 or player 2?

Comment: Why not transpose first before calculating the frequencies.  Then PROC FREQ will generate the proper statistics for you.  If you add the PERCENTAGE variable they will total to 200% instead of 100%.  Adding the cumulative statistics doesn't make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Does it work for you?

```
data combined / view=combined;
set table1 table2;
run;

proc means data=combined nway;
class player1;
var Fréquence,Pourcentage,Fréquence cumulée,Pourcentage cumulé;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can join this to table using proc sql and summary function.

Have1 dataset:

```
+---------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
|       player1       | Frequence | Pourcentage | Frequencecumulee | Pourcentagecumule |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
| Adrian Mannarino    |         3 |        1.18 |                3 |              1.18 |
| Agnieszka Radwanska |         2 |        0.79 |                5 |              1.97 |
| Ajla Tomljanovic    |         1 |        0.39 |                6 |              2.36 |
| Albert Ramos        |         1 |        0.39 |                7 |              2.76 |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Have2 dataset:

```
+------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
|     player2      | Frequence | Pourcentage | Frequencecumulee | Pourcentagecumule |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
| Adrian Mannarino |         1 |        0.39 |                1 |              0.39 |
| Alex Bolt        |         1 |        0.39 |                2 |              0.79 |
| Alex De Minaur   |         1 |        0.39 |                3 |              1.18 |
| Alexander Zverev |         3 |        1.18 |                6 |              2.36 |
+------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Solution:

```
proc sql noprint;
   create table want1 as
   select 
            coalesce(player1,player2) as player,
            sum(t1.Frequence,t2.Frequence) as Frequence,
            sum(t1.Pourcentage,t2.Pourcentage) as Pourcentage,
            sum(t1.Frequencecumulee,t2.Frequencecumulee) as Frequencecumulee,
            sum(t1.Pourcentagecumule,t2.Pourcentagecumule) as Pourcentagecumule
   from
            have1 t1
   full join 
            have2 t2
   on
            strip(player1)=strip(player2);
quit;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
|       player        | Frequence | Pourcentage | Frequencecumulee | Pourcentagecumule |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
| Adrian Mannarino    |         4 |        1.57 |                4 |              1.57 |
| Agnieszka Radwanska |         2 |        0.79 |                5 |              1.97 |
| Ajla Tomljanovic    |         1 |        0.39 |                6 |              2.36 |
| Albert Ramos        |         1 |        0.39 |                7 |              2.76 |
| Alex Bolt           |         1 |        0.39 |                2 |              0.79 |
| Alex De Minaur      |         1 |        0.39 |                3 |              1.18 |
| Alexander Zverev    |         3 |        1.18 |                6 |              2.36 |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Or you can try to use data step + proc summary:

```
data want2;
  set have2(rename=(player2=player)) have1(rename=(player1=player));
run;

proc summary data=want2 nway;
  var Frequence Pourcentage Frequencecumulee Pourcentagecumule;
  class player;
  output out=want2 (drop=_:) sum=;
run;
```

Output:

```
+---------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
|       player        | Frequence | Pourcentage | Frequencecumulee | Pourcentagecumule |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
| Adrian Mannarino    |         4 |        1.57 |                4 |              1.57 |
| Agnieszka Radwanska |         2 |        0.79 |                5 |              1.97 |
| Ajla Tomljanovic    |         1 |        0.39 |                6 |              2.36 |
| Albert Ramos        |         1 |        0.39 |                7 |              2.76 |
| Alex Bolt           |         1 |        0.39 |                2 |              0.79 |
| Alex De Minaur      |         1 |        0.39 |                3 |              1.18 |
| Alexander Zverev    |         3 |        1.18 |                6 |              2.36 |
+---------------------+-----------+-------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use the ODS table output instead. This gives you a nice clean version. The table called `temp` is the output from proc freq and then I clean it up into a displayable table called `want`. It's pretty generic so change your data set names and variable names in the first step and everything else should work.

```
*Run frequency for tables;
ods table onewayfreqs=temp;
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
    table sex age;
run;

*Format output;
data want;
length variable $32. variable_value $50.;
set temp;
Variable=scan(table, 2);

Variable_Value=strip(trim(vvaluex(variable)));

keep variable variable_value frequency percent cum:;
label variable='Variable' 
    variable_value='Variable Value';
run;

*Display;
proc print data=want(obs=20) label;
run;
```